# How does a browser get music metadata from web players?

Tags: audio, browser, website, metadata

When I listen to music on Plex Web / YouTube on Vivaldi (Chromium), my desktop sound applet (I use Cinnamon, but I assume it works the same for any desktop and OS) shows title and artist (and theoretically album art) and allows me to play / pause. Same on the lockscreen. Apparently this is thanks to the MPRIS2 standard, which Chromium implements. But how does Chromium itself interface with the different websites? Is this some sort of HTML / Javascript standard so that I can expose that functionality from my own web music player or does the browser need to include modules for every page it supports?